# How to convert Model List to Json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create an json data similar to this https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/world-mortality.json

The current output I am getting is like this. The model name is being displayed and child does not seems to work. is t possible to remove the model field name on the serialize?

```
[{Name:"ABC",
        Firstchild:[{Name:"AIR IMPORT",
            Secondchild:[{NAME:"SCMBOA00052997",VALUE:69.7500},
                {NAME:"SH123",VALUE:-100.0000},
                {NAME:"SH456",VALUE:50.0000},
                {NAME:"SH789",VALUE:150.0000}]
            }]
 }{Name:"DEF",
        Firstchild:[{Name:"AIR IMPORT",
            Secondchild:[{NAME:"SCMBOA00052997",VALUE:69.7500},
                {NAME:"SH111",VALUE:-10.0000},
                {NAME:"SH222",VALUE:80.0000},
                {NAME:"SH333",VALUE:160.0000}]
            }]
 }]
```

What I need is like this

```
{
    "ABC": {
        "AIR IMPORT":{
            "SH123": -100.0000,
            "SH456": 50.0000,
            "SH789": 150.0000
        }
    },
    "DEF": {
        "AIR IMPORT":{
            "SH111": -10.0000,
            "SH222": 80.0000,
            "SH333": 160.0000
        }
    }
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public class ParentTreemap
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<FirstChildTreemap> Firstchild { get; set; }
}

public class FirstChildTreemap
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SecondChildTreemap> Secondchild { get; set; }
}

public class SecondChildTreemap
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
var parent = treemaplist.Where(s => s.Parent == 0);
        List<ParentTreemap> plist = new List<ParentTreemap>();
        foreach (var item in parent)
        {
            var firstchild = treemaplist.Where(s => s.Parent == item.Id && s.Value==0);
            List<FirstChildTreemap> flist = new List<FirstChildTreemap>();
            foreach (var fitem in firstchild)
            {
                var secondchild = treemaplist.Where(s => s.Parent == fitem.Id && s.Value!=0);
                List<SecondChildTreemap> slist = new List<SecondChildTreemap>();
                foreach (var sitem in secondchild)
                {
                    SecondChildTreemap model = new SecondChildTreemap();
                    model.Name = sitem.Name;
                    model.Value = sitem.Value;
                    slist.Add(model);
                }
                FirstChildTreemap child = new FirstChildTreemap();
                child.Name = fitem.Name;
                child.Secondchild = slist;
                flist.Add(child);
            }
            ParentTreemap pmodel = new ParentTreemap();
            pmodel.Name = item.Name;
            pmodel.Firstchild = flist;
            plist.Add(pmodel);
        }
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter))
        {
            writer.QuoteName = false;
            serializer.Serialize(writer, plist);
        }
        ViewData["result"] = stringWriter;
```

Comment: Your Property and Value both are dynamic?!

Comment: @Valkyrie yes it is depends on the value of name

Comment: The JSON you posted as a link has fixed properties for each elements, you're trying to get dynamic properties for each object. You cannot achieve this with a single object definition without using arrays/lists as you already doing.

Comment: You should use dynamic instead of creating classes. you can't serialize these classes into that output JSON.